# Trying to find a Lifecycle hook that worked after switching to a new page VUE

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, hook, lifecycle

I have page transition animation.
I want after transition find on new page element and change style.
My problem I first change the element and then go to a new page where this element is not changed.
Here link on video how its work now https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VvmVxd-cmNM

Comment: Any code you can share?

Comment: @doesnotmatter [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-dust-i68cp?file=/src/App.vue)
Here code of my component where I make transition animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I get this right but I'll try to answer anyway

> I want after transition find on new page element and change style.

Vue `<transition>` has events for when you want to know if a transition is done.

You might be able to use `@leave` or `@after-leave`.

Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks

> My problem I first change the element and then go to a new page where this element is not changed.

You are structuring your app incorrectly.

I watched the video and it looks like both pages includes your Nav/Sidebar (the right part) thing in each page.

**You** are structuring your page like this:

PageA.vue

```html
<div id="page-a">
  <!-- this is your left side part -->
  <div id="page-a-content"></div>

  <!-- this is your right side part -->
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

PageB.vue

```html
<div id="page-b">
  <!-- this is your left side part -->
  <div id="page-b-content"></div>

  <!-- this is your right side part -->
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

App.vue

```html
<div>
  <!-- This shows PageA.vue OR PageB.vue -->
  <router-view />
</div>
```

---

You **only** have the left-side part changing but not the right-side part.

You should structure it like this:

App.vue

```html
<div>
  <!-- This is your left side part. PageA.vue OR PageB.vue -->
  <router-view />
 
  <!-- This is your right side part -->
  <Sidebar />
</div>
```

When you change your page, **only** the `<router-view />` will change and **not** the `<Sidebar />`

Comment: God thank you! So much useful information! I don't knowed about @leave after-leave hooks. in monday I will try what you recommend. Anyway thank you

Comment: App.vue

<div>
  <!-- This is your left side part. PageA.vue OR PageB.vue -->
  <router-view />
 
  <!-- This is your right side part -->
  <Sidebar />
</div>